# java animation sound not playing properly

Tags: java, swing, audio, javasound

A ball is moving up and down in an infinite loop. Sound is supposed to play for each movement. But it is being played for every 5-6 movements. Why is that happening? Sound duration is less than 1 second. In the code there is a sleep for 3 seconds in each iteration of the loop. However, changing the sleep duration to 6 seconds, achieves the required effect.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import sun.audio.*;
import java.io.*;

public class dabble {

private boolean z=false;
private int x=10;
private int y=10;
private JFrame frame;
private JLabel label;
private mypanel panel;
private JButton b1;
private JButton b2;

public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
    dabble dab = new dabble();
    dab.start();
}

void start()
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    label = new JLabel();
    panel = new mypanel();
    b1= new JButton("Start");
    b2= new JButton("Stop");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    b1.addActionListener(new al1());
    b2.addActionListener(new al2());

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH,b1);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,b2);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,panel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST,label);
    frame.setSize(600,600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

class al1 implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        if (z==false)
        {
            class myrun implements Runnable{
                public void run(){
                    z=true;
                    while(z==true)
                    {
                        y=510-y;
                        panel.repaint();
                        try
                        {
                            InputStream in=new FileInputStream("hit.wav");
                            AudioStream as=new AudioStream(in);
                            AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                        }
                        catch(Exception Ex){}
                    }
                }
            }

            Runnable myjob = new myrun();
            Thread mythread = new Thread(myjob);
            mythread.start();

        }
    }
}

class al2 implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        z=false;
    }
}

class mypanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent ( Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
        int red = (int) (Math.random()*255);
        int green = (int) (Math.random()*255);
        int blue = (int) (Math.random()*255);
        Color c1 = new Color(red,green,blue);
        g.setColor(c1);
        g.fillOval(x,y,20,20);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Load the sound in a [`Clip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html) as shown on the [JavaSound info.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) page.
2. Clip offers a [`loop(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#loop%28int%29) method to specify the number of time to play.

Comment: this does not work,moreover with this movement has become random and sound does not play

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would change is the loading of the audio file in the while loop.  This could be a lengthy operation that is messing up the timing.

Add the `AudioStream as` as a private member variable of the `al1` class and initialize it in the constructor.  Then, each time the loop iterates, you already have the stream ready to go and you can just play it.

Comment: I tried running the code, but with javax.sound.sampled SourceDataLine, and got the same error. Moving code to the constructor didn't help much. Was still having the sound come in rather late on occasion, though the occasions were down to the 1 in 30 range. Very curious.

Answer (score 0):

When I move the sleep command to outside the try block, but still within the while loop, there is still some unevenness in how long the loop takes, but at least the ball and sound stay in sync.

Really weird, though. I can't figure out why the sleep placement matters. It is as if the sleep, when in the try block, doesn't get executed until after the new repaint has occurred, and thus holds up the next play? But how could that be?